# Duplicate files copied in APK Android - Can it be merged?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

In my android project I have included two libraries as JARs into libs folder. And I add them to the build Gradle as below.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/siddhi-core-4.0.0-M13-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/siddhi-execution-math-4.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

Those two jar files the have a file with the same name ("org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension") but with different content. And both files are important for the project.
Since it has same name gradle won't build saying

```
Duplicate files copied in APK
```

How can I merge those two files into one single file with the same name?
Those two files are text files with a list of Class names. In two files they have two different lists. So I want to merge them into one list in a text file with same name.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. In the app build gradle you can specify to merge the conflicting files.

```
packagingOptions {         
    merge 'META-INF/annotations/org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension'
}
```

for details look here https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the file from jar by unzip them first and copy the jar without those files,
After that compile that unZip copy file instead of the actual file, like this

```
task unzipJar(type: Copy) {
   from zipTree('libs/siddhi-core-4.0.0-M13-SNAPSHOT.jar')
   into ("$buildDir/libs/siddhi-core-4.0.0-M13-SNAPSHOT")
   include "**/*.class"
   exclude "org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension"
}

dependencies {
   compile files('libs/siddhi-execution-math-4.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')
   compile files("$buildDir/libs/siddhi-core-4.0.0-M13-SNAPSHOT") {
      builtBy "unzipJar"
   }
}
```

Please check this, even I didn't get the chance to use it but it should work.

Comment: But it's not what it's asked : *How can I keep both these files or merge them into one single file?*

Comment: Why do you required same file twice?

Comment: The content of the two files are different. It contains list of extensions which is scanned later in the program

Comment: its strange two different functionality files with the same name and package.

Comment: "org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension" is a text file which has list of classes. It is essential to have all the content in those files in one file for the execution of some other class.

Comment: Although this is a nice code to bookmark, sadly this doesn't answer the question. Nevertheless, deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can not as both files having same name resolution.(org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension).
So it will not going to work .
Lets say some how you have included both the jars than how you are going to use one of them
ie. How runtime will uniquely identify the class as both class have same namespace as well as name.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
 dependencies {
       compile files('libs/siddhi-execution-math-4.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')
       compile files("$buildDir/libs/siddhi-core-4.0.0-M13-SNAPSHOT") {
          builtBy "unzipJar"
       }
    }
```